# Scaffolding Get-ProjectType not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, powershell, asp.net-mvc-4, scaffolding, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

just tried to get the basic basics up and running and getting some fancy error conditions - most probably some basic steps are screwed up but I don't see the point - so some hints are highly appreciated.

**So whats the setup?**

- VS2010
- MVC3 or MVC4 Project - no strings attached, just the templates
- Create a really simple Model-Class Team like shown on http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/

**What happens?**

Try (after installing MvcScaffolding through NuGet Console) to call:

```
Scaffold Controller Team
```

And get the following error:

```
PM> Scaffold Controller Team
Scaffolding TeamsController...
Invoke-Scaffolder : The term 'Get-ProjectType' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At O:\Code\Resource\packages\MvcScaffolding.1.0.7\tools\Controller\MvcScaffolding.Controller.ps1:66 char:40
+         $dbContextScaffolderResult = Scaffold <<<<  DbContext -ModelType $foundModelType.FullName -DbContextType $DbContextType -Area $Area -Project $Project -CodeLang
uage $CodeLanguage -BlockUi
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-Scaffolder], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : T4Scaffolding.Cmdlets.InvokeScaffolderCmdlet
```

Fancy thing: of course Get-ProjectType itself seems to work (see below), so I'm kind of stuck right now - as this looks like a powershell issue somehow but the cmdlet itself works at least if called directly but not when inside the script? Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks a lot.

```
PM> Get-ProjectType
cmdlet Get-ProjectType at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Type: Team


DTE                   : System.__ComObject
Collection            : System.__ComObject
Name                  : Team
FullName              : Resource.Models.Team
ProjectItem           : System.__ComObject
Kind                  : 1
IsCodeType            : True
InfoLocation          : 1
Children              : System.__ComObject
Language              : {B5E9BD34-6D3E-4B5D-925E-8A43B79820B4}
StartPoint            : System.__ComObject
EndPoint              : System.__ComObject
ExtenderNames         : 
ExtenderCATID         : 
Parent                : System.__ComObject
Namespace             : System.__ComObject
Bases                 : System.__ComObject
Members               : System.__ComObject
Access                : 1
Attributes            : System.__ComObject
DocComment            : <doc>
                        </doc>
Comment               : 
DerivedTypes          : 
ImplementedInterfaces : System.__ComObject
IsAbstract            : False
ClassKind             : 1
PartialClasses        : System.__ComObject
DataTypeKind          : 1
Parts                 : System.__ComObject
InheritanceKind       : 0
IsGeneric             : False
IsShared              : False



PM>
```

With Kind Regards,
Ives

Comment: hi, did you get this sorted out ? in the same situation now.

Comment: nope but I havn't tried for a while, most probably it works now... if I get some news about this I'll update it. But I guess latest version did resolve this issues - not confirmed!